# Barcode reader for browser in windows

Tags: barcode-scanner

I was working on a desktop app in window in which user scan bar code to system using bar code reader machine.
But now  when i m trying same thing for browser i m not getting any idea how to do that ,please help   me !!!.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a javascript library that'll do it called **[QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/examples/)**

Comment: Thanks Le-roy but it that will not run on all browser and  it uses system camera . but want  it for bar code scanner machine. thanks again for replying  do u have any other work around

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything compatible with a 'standard' barcode scanner that doesn't support image capture... browsers would have to provide an API to support the communication and barcode scanners don't seem like they'd be popular enough to do that. You *could* write a process that sits on the client machine and acts as the communication layer between your web platform and the barcode scanner...

Comment: Also - don't many standard barcode scanners convert it to key strokes on the keyboard? So it's like typing in text? Might be able to utilize that somehow...

Comment: Thanks for help le-roy :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I needed to read barcodes into a browser and then do something with them.  You can set most handheld scanners to supply a character on copletion of the scan so I used this.

First I set up a simple input box on the screen

```
<div>Test Read</div>
<input id='testRead' value=''/>
<div id="testReadResult"></div>
```

Next I used a simple bit of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#testRead").focusout(function() {
            testReader(jQuery( "#testRead" ).val());
        });                      
    });
    function testReader(value){
       console.log("value received is "+value);
       jQuery("#testReadResult").html(value);
   }
 </script>
```

You simply click on the first box and then scan the barcode.  The numbers for the barcode appear in the box and then appear in the div below it.

I've extended this to make it user friendly etc but this is working code that will get you started.  You need to set your scanner to have a TAB termination character.

Comment: What's wrong with answering old questions?